# What is the best way to generate and run concurent threads from a for loop over an Arc<Mutex<Vec>>?

Tags: rust

Im running both a uni and multi threaded version of an application. There is no speed advantage. That said, what is the best way to access an `Arc<Mutex<Vec>>` and process each entry concurrently?

Comment: You cannot access the inner value of an `Arc<Mutex<_>>` concurrently, the Mutex prevents this by design. Perhaps you can copy/move elements out and process them that way? Or perhaps inverting your structure to `Vec<Arc<Mutex<_>>>` so that each entry is protected independently? There's not enough info here to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot process an `Arc<Mutex<Vec<T>>>` concurrently - the mutex wraps the entire vector, so no other thread other than the one that locked it will be able to access it.

If you know the number of elements up front, you can use an `Arc<Vec<Mutex<T>>>`. This has a mutex per-element, so threads will lock only the elements. However you won't be able to grow or shrink the `Vec` since its shared.

There are also more specialized structures in the Concurrency section of http://lib.rs, with varying semantics, that may fit your needs.